# Skew custom layout

Tags: android, layout, android-canvas, skew

I've got custom layout and I skew it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.skew(0f, 0.2f);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

And I achieve this [image]

Although, I want to skew it from the other side (I want right higher than left) so I decided to flip it horizontally like this

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.scale(-1f, 1f, super.getWidth() * 0.5f, super.getHeight() * 0.5f);
    canvas.skew(0f, 0.2f);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

But then button, as you can see below, flips too. Can you suggest me how to flip only Layout but not children inside?

[image]